# How to clear EditText using onClick when I click on the entered text?

Tags: javascript, android, onclick, android-edittext

I've tried lots of code under the same question on here, but nothing seems to work. I want to be able to enter the text, then press a button to display that text - it all works fine.

Then when the user clicks back into the EditText field, the old text should clear. Right now, whenever I enter the text and press enter, all of the text disappears. Please help. This is the code:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextInput);
       editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
       {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (v == editText);
                editText.getText().clear(); } });}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass the empty string in edit text like

```
editText.setText("")
```

it will make your edit text empty

Comment: That still does exactly what my code already does. When I press "enter" the text disappears. I want to enter the text, then when I click on it later it will clear

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand why you are using if condition I think you don't need it.
but in any case use this code.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    editText.getText().clear(); //or you can use editText.setText("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you use textWatcher, and you add the listener on `afterTextChanged` and remove the listener on `beforeTextChanged`. Maybe can do the trick

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
    editText.removeTextChangedListener(<yourListner>)}
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
    editText.setOnClickListener(<yourListner>)}
            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
        })
```